# Possible class error?

Tags: java

```
class Randomagain {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner tuna = new Scanner(System.in); 
        boom boomObj = new boom();
        System.out.println("~~Calculator~~");
        System.out.print("Enter your 1st number: "); int first_num = tuna.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter your 2nd number: "); int second_num = tuna.nextInt();

        System.out.print("What do you want to do? [plus,sub,mult,div]:  "); 
        String choice = tuna.nextLine();
        if (choice == "plus") boomObj.addition(first_num, second_num);
        if (choice == "sub") boomObj.subtraction(first_num, second_num);
        if (choice == "mult") boomObj.multiply(first_num, second_num);
        if (choice == "div") boomObj.division(first_num, second_num); 
        else {System.out.println("Please check the fields again!! ");}
    }
}
```

boom class:

```
public class boom {
    private int sub_final, add_final, multi_final, div_final;
    public void addition(int a, int b){
        add_final = a + b; System.out.println(a+ " + " +b+ " = " +add_final);
    }

    public void subtraction(int a, int b){
        sub_final = a - b; System.out.println(a+ " - " +b+ " = " +sub_final);
    }

    public void multiply(int a, int b){
        multi_final = a * b; System.out.println(a+ " * " +b+ " = " +multi_final);
    }

    public void division(int a, int b){
        div_final = a + b; System.out.println(a+ " / " +b+ " = " +add_final);
    }
}
```

When I run it, in the 3rd command, it is like :

```
What do you want to do? [plus,sub,mult,div]:  Please check the fields again!!
```

And I can't type anything as its reply.

Comment: That's because after it prints that error message your program ends. Also, you can't check `String` equivalence with `==`, you have to use `equals()`.

Comment: Why didn't the program wait for the reply from the user for "What do you want to do?"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the `choice` with literal string using `equals` method, not by using `==`. The reason is that `==` checks whether the compared variables refer to the same string object, which in your case is not.

So, replace:

```
                 if (choice == "plus") boomObj.addition(first_num, second_num);
                  if (choice == "sub") boomObj.subtraction(first_num, second_num);
                  if (choice == "mult") boomObj.multiply(first_num, second_num);
                  if (choice == "div") boomObj.division(first_num, second_num); 
                 else {System.out.println("Please check the fields again!! ");
```

with

```
                 if (choice.equals("plus")) boomObj.addition(first_num, second_num);
                  if (choice.equals("sub")) boomObj.subtraction(first_num, second_num);
                  if (choice.equals("mult")) boomObj.multiply(first_num, second_num);
                  if (choice.equals("div")) boomObj.division(first_num, second_num); 
                 else {System.out.println("Please check the fields again!! ");
```

Answer (score 1):

`tuna.nextLine()` will read all the content in the `InputStream` until it finds a line break (line separator), which is the empty text between the second number you entered and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Change it to `tuna.next()` to make this work.

Apart of that, you should compare `String`s using `equals` method, not using `==`:

```
//if (choice == "plus")
if (choice.equals("plus")) {
    //...
}
```

Another problem in your code is that the last `else` sentence only affects to the closest `if` statement. Your code is currently:

```
if (choice.equals("plus") { }
if (choice.equals("sub") { }
if (choice.equals("mul") { }
if (choice.equals("div") { } else { } //only affects here
```

Which means that if you enter some text different that `"div"` the program will always execute the code in the `else` statement. Your code should change to:

```
if (choice.equals("plus") { }
else if (choice.equals("sub") { }
else if (choice.equals("mul") { }
else if (choice.equals("div") { } else { }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I am new to Java, so I wasn't sure about the proper syntax for string functions.. :)